# Clear and Done action in Filter

Tags: interaction-design, android, filter, actions

I need to define where and how (icon or text) to locate the clear and done actions inside a filter.

I have 2 options. One using icons and the other using text.

Basically we are thinking a very similar solution as the one that amazon uses but we need a "done" action too.

The main idea is that after the user performed a search, he goes to the search results page where he can filters his results and refine by this a little more.

When he starts setting the filters a "done" or "clear" (that sets all filters back to default state) should appear.

Finally, I have seen that google material handles "done" with a check icon. This is great, but...which icon should work for "reset"? I searched a little bit and found out that some apps use the "refresh" icon. But for me, this icon means more refresh than reset for users.

could you help me with the placing of these two actions for the filter? and which option do you think is best? icons or text? and if icons are best for actions in android, which icon could I use for reset?

Thanks in advance for your help! =)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current context, i think the system should speak what the user can understand without thinking about it. I agree to your apprehension in using the clear icon, it does look like the refresh and it would be unnecessary to use an icon here when text could easily fit in.

Here is an interesting thread on what might make it clear for you : [Icon vs Icon Text vs Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1I0J.png)

I would go with **Option 1** , I think the presence of the text here is literally invisible.

Here are 2 examples from Airbnb and Hotels.com apps
[image]